# setup aiohttp_jinja2 for multiple loader

Tags: python, aiohttp

i want to setup aiohttp_jinja2 for multiple loader (PackageLoader, FileSystemLoader), for example:

```
def setup_template_engine(app):
    aiohttp_jinja2.setup(app, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(str(Path('.') / 'templates')))
    aiohttp_jinja2.setup(app, loader=jinja2.PackageLoader('app', 'templates')) # in this case, only last setup works
```

and **question** is: how to setup aiohttp_jinja2 for multiple loader?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might think about creating multiple environments, as suggested here: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/api/#basics

There they say:

> Most applications will create one Environment object on application initialization and use that to load templates. In some cases however, it’s useful to have multiple environments side by side, if different configurations are in use.

Then you would have one environment with the FileSystemLoader and one with the PackageLoader